# Working with global Dictionary inside threads

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Suppose that I have a `Dictionary<string, string>`. The dictionary is declared as `public static` in my console program.

If I'm working with threads and I want to do `foreach` on this `Dictionary` from one thread but at the same time another thread want to add item to the dictionary. This would cause a bug here because we can't modify our `Dictionary` while we are running on it with a foreach loop in another thread.

To bypass this problem I created a lock statement on the same static object on each operation on the dictionary.

Is this the best way to bypass this problem? My `Dictionary` can be very big and I can have many threads that want to foreach on it. As it is currently, things can be very slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), which is designed for this kind of scenario.

There's a nice tutorial [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/17/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrentdictionary.aspx) on how to use it.

Comment: You have to be careful with the `foreach` the OP needs though, since it isn't a snapshot it can be buggy to `foreach` on a `ConcurrentDictionary`  unless you can either cope with it changing as you work on it, or add the snapshot yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The big question is: Do you need the `foreach` to be a snapshot?

If the answer is "no", then use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and you will probably be fine. (The one remaining question is whether the nature of your inserts and reads hit the striped locks in a bad way, but if that was the case you'd be finding normal reads and writes to the dictionary even worse).

However, because it's `GetEnumerator` doesn't provide a snapshot, it will not be enumerating the same start at the beginning as it is at the end. It could miss items, or duplicate items. The question is whether that's a disaster to you or not.

If it would be a disaster if you had duplicates, but not otherwise, then you can filter out duplicates with `Distinct()` (whether keyed on the keys or both the key and value, as required).

If you really need it to be a hard snapshot, then take the following approach.

Have a `ConcurrentDictionary` (`dict`) and a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (`rwls`). On both reads and writes obtain a reader lock (yes even though you're writing):

```
public static void AddToDict(string key, string value)
{
  rwls.EnterReadLock();
  try
  {
    dict[key] = value;
  }
  finally
  {
    rwls.ExitReadLock();
  }
}
public static bool ReadFromDict(string key, out string value)
{
  rwls.EnterReadLock();
  try
  {
    return dict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
  }
  finally
  {
    rwls.ExitReadLock();
  }
}
```

Now, when we want to enumerate the dictionary, we acquire the write lock (even though we're reading):

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> EnumerateDict()
{
  rwls.EnterWriteLock();
  try
  {
    return dict.ToList();
  }
  finally
  {
    rwls.ExitWriteLock();
  }
}
```

This way we obtain the shared lock for reading and writing, because `ConcurrentDictionary` deals with the conflicts involved in that for us. We obtain the exclusive lock for enumerating, but just for long enough to obtain a snapshot of the dictionary in a list, which is then used only in that thread and not shared with any other.

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 4 you get a fancy new [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). I think there are some .NET 3.5-based implementations floating around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have a problem updating the global dictionary while an enumeration is running in another thread.

Solutions:

1. Require all users of the dictionary to acquire a mutex lock before accessing the object, and release the lock afterwards.
2. Use .NET 4.0's ConcurrentDictionary class.